# Is there a way to use pyspark.sql.functions.date_add with a col('column_name') as a the second parameter instead of a static integer?

Tags: pyspark

During an ETL process I have this one SAS date field that is in a 5 digit integer format, which indicates days since 01-01-1960. I order to make this data column more useful in analysis I would like to convert the column to a date data type field in Redshift.

Currently I am trying to do this in pyspark as follows:

- created new column "sas_date" with string literal "1960-01-01"
- Using pyspark.sql.function.date_add I pass the "sas-date" column as 
  the start date parameter and the integer value 'arrival_date' column as the second parameter.
- When the date_add function runs I get error Column not iterable, even though I would think the arrival_date column being a series would mean it was iterable. But its not, why?
- When I remove the 'arrival_date' column and replace it with a static integer value (say 1) the date_add function will work.

```py
i94 = i94.withColumn('arrival_date', col('arrival_date').cast(Int()))
i94 = i94.withColumn('sas_date', lit("1960-01-01"))
i94 = i94.withColumn('arrival_date', date_add(col('sas_date'), i94['arrival_date']))
```

I want to be able to pass my column so that the second date_add parameter will be dynamic. However it seems date_add does not accept this? If date_addd does not accomplish this what other option do I have outside of using a UDF?

**UPDATE:**
State of data right before the date_add() operation

```py
i94.printSchema()
```

root

|-- cic_id: double (nullable = true)

|-- visa_id: string (nullable = true)

|-- port_id: string (nullable = true)

|-- airline_id: string (nullable = true)

|-- cit_id: double (nullable = true)

|-- res_id: double (nullable = true)

|-- year: double (nullable = true)

|-- month: double (nullable = true)

|-- age: double (nullable = true)

|-- gender: string (nullable = true)

|-- arrival_date: integer (nullable = true)

|-- depart_date: double (nullable = true)

|-- date_begin: string (nullable = true)

|-- date_end: string (nullable = true)

|-- sas_date: string (nullable = false)

```py
i94.limit(10).toPandas()
```

[toPandas() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti05J.png)

Comment: It Should work with your approach. can you show some sample data,

Comment: Right @SMaZ ? Although I think I just realized why it behaves this way. When using withColumn('arrival_date',...)  I think spark overwrites the 'arrival_date' column before it even applies the date_add sql function.  I am going to test this theory later and will update answer to the question if I'm right.

Comment: a@Mabloq: You don't need to evaluate `arrival_date` twice. Can you show data like what is arrival_date value at first place.

Comment: Note that SAS stores all numbers as floating point. So perhaps you just need to convert your raw number of days variable values to integers to get it to work with date_add()?

Comment: Hey @SMaZ thanks for sticking with me. I edited my quesion with schema data and 10 row sample. My theory was disproven :(

Comment: @Tom That's not the case this time. I showed in my question that I convert the arrivale date column to  Int before the date_add operation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are absolutely right, `date_add` is designed to take `int` values only till **Spark <3.0.0**:

In spark scala implementation i see below lines. 
It indicates that whatever value we pass it to function `date_add` it is converting again into column with `lit`

[**Spark <3.0.0**:](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala)

> def date_add(start: Column, days: Int): Column = date_add(start,
>   lit(days))

[**Spark >=3.0.0**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala):

> def date_add(start: Column, days: Column): Column = withExpr {
>   DateAdd(start.expr, days.expr) }

- Now lets talk about Solution, i can think of two approaches :

Imports and prepare small set of your dataset:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

l1 = [(5748517.0,'1960-01-01', 20574), (5748517.0,'1960-01-01', 20574), (5748517.0,'1960-01-01', 20574)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('cic_id','sas_date','arrival_date')
df.show()
+---------+----------+------------+
|   cic_id|  sas_date|arrival_date|
+---------+----------+------------+
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Now, there are two ways to achive functionality.

1. **UDF Way :**

```
def date_add_(date, days):

    # Type check and convert to datetime object
    # Format and other things should be handle more delicately
    if type(date) is not datetime:
        date = datetime.strptime('1960-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
    return date + timedelta(days)


date_add_udf = f.udf(date_add_, t.DateType())

df.withColumn('actual_arrival_date', date_add_udf(f.to_date('sas_date'), 'arrival_date')).show()
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------+
|   cic_id|  sas_date|arrival_date|actual_arrival_date|
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------+
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|         2016-04-30|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|         2016-04-30|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|         2016-04-30|
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------+
```

2. **Using `expr` evaluation :**

```
df.withColumn('new_arrival_date', f.expr("date_add(sas_date, arrival_date)")).show()
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
|   cic_id|  sas_date|arrival_date|new_arrival_date|
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|      2016-04-30|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|      2016-04-30|
|5748517.0|1960-01-01|       20574|      2016-04-30|
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, nice job digging that out from source. Also good to know that the column option will be available in 3.0.

Comment: Also for future comer's reference, the udf method was tested and worked. Thanks again @SMaz

Comment: It appears 3+ did not fix it: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#date_add :(

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spark Python API 3.3.0 you can pass a column as second parameter to date_add function : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#date_add